# Equicontinuity, Beltrami coefficients and Sequence of top/bottom semi-annuli

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, teichmuller-theory, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal

In the Beltrami equation literature, one approach to showing equicontinuity for pairs $(f_{n},\mu_{n})$ (where $\partial_{\bar{z}}f_{n}=\mu_{n}(z)\partial_{z}f_{n}$) is via the relations of moduli and dilatation (eg. see Lehto condition chapter [here](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691137773/elliptic-partial-differential-equations-and-quasiconformal-mappings) and also online thm 4.1 [here](http://www.cajpn.org/sugawa/papers/modulus2010.pdf) which covers our setting of having $\mu_{n}\to \mu$ with degenerate $\|\mu\|_{\infty}=1$). For example, for topological annulus $\Omega=\mathbb{C}\setminus E\cup F$ where $F$ is the unbounded component, we have:

$$mod(\Omega)\leq \Phi(\frac{dist(E,F)}{diam(E)})$$

for some increasing function $\Phi$. So in the case of showing equicontinuity $diam(f_{n}( B_{r}(z)))\to 0$ as $r\to 0$ (*), we let $E_{r}:=f_{n}( B_{r}(z))$, $\Omega:=f_{n}(B_{1}(z)\setminus B_{r}(z))$ and so in order to get (*) we ask the modulus to diverge

$$\Phi(\frac{dist(E_{r},E_{1})}{diam(E_{r})})\geq mod(f_{n}(B_{1}(z)\setminus B_{r}(z)))\to \infty, \text{ as }n\to +\infty.(**)$$

In our problem, the Beltrami coefficient is of the form

$$\mu(z):=\left\{\begin{matrix} \mu_{+}(z)&z\in \mathbb{D}  \\ \mu_{-}(z)&z\in \bar{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\bar{\mathbb{D}}\end{matrix}\right..$$

We have shown (**) in the case $\mu_{1}(z):=\left\{\begin{matrix} \mu_{+}(z)&z\in \mathbb{D}  \\ 0&z\in \bar{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\bar{\mathbb{D}}\end{matrix}\right.$ and similarly for $\mu_{2}(z)$. In particular, let $f_{1,n}$ correspond to $\mu_{1,n}(z):=\frac{n}{n+1}\mu_{1}(z)$, I lower bounded the modulus over some special choice of annuli $A_{1,k}\subset B_{1}(z)$ (for our particular coefficients) and showed

$$mod(f_{1,n}(B_{1}(z)\setminus B_{r}(z)))\geq \sum_{k=1}^{n}mod(f_{1,n}(A_{1,k}))\geq a_{1} n.$$

Similarly for $f_{2,n}$ for some choice $A_{2,k}\subset B_{1}(z)$. Now the problem is to find a choice of annuli that will give $(**)$ for the combined Beltrami coefficient $\mu(z)$. The most reasonable one is to see if one can re-choose the $A_{1,k},A_{2,k}$ so that they intersect $A_{1,k}\cap A_{2,k}$ with a large enough overlap to give $(**)$.

> Q: I understand this is a specialized niche problem, so I am mainly interested in advice/references for studying branch Beltrami coefficients like $\mu(z)$. Maybe phrased in a different language. In particular, I want to find ways/frameworks. Possibly generalized Lehto inequalities (eg. lemma 7.1 in [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-3191-6)) that could work well for studying branch $\mu$.